# Why does smoothScrollTo() not scroll to the bottom?

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview

I'm just wondering what this does.

I've tried using:

```
scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollView.bottom)
```

, but it doesn't even scroll all the way to the bottom...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the code below. It should work for you.

```java
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollView.bottom);
    }
});
```

## Kotlin:

```
scrollView.post { scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollView.bottom) }
```

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear.**

Comment: Oh it works thank you for the answer. It scrolled all the way to the bottom. :)

Comment: Glad to help you. Kindly upvote the answer if possible.